# Facebook Group with a Restricted Friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-privacy

On Facebook, I've got my boss as a "Restricted Friend" so he isn't seeing my posts unless I make them public. Now, he's joined a Group that I manage. Will he be able to see posts I make to the group's page?

Answer (score 1):

If he is in the group you are managing and if you are posting something then only in that group he is able to view your posts but not all the other posts.